# Avoiding struts 2 generated Java scripting and HTML code in <s: form> tag

Tags: forms, struts2

I'm using struts 2 `<s:form>` tag. Now I want use design prepared by our design team. So I have to intrigate my struts specific code with normal HTML design. The problem is that the `<s:form>` tag generates the `<table>` HTML code and `<s:textfield>` generating `<tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>`.

So my question is how to avoid the generating the HTML code form struts.

Comment: You could also just use an HTML form. You don't have to use the struts tags.

Comment: If i use HTML form then i wont'get struts feature like maintening state.

Comment: You can also [set a default theme](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/selecting-themes.html) to avoid having to specify the theme everywhere.

Comment: @Shweta Not sure what you are talking about, but there is virtually no difference between the <form> and <s:form>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want avoid struts 2 generated java script or HTML code then  use the simple theme.like below

```
<s:form action="loginAction" theme="simple">
```

struts2 have  different theme and template. you can design your own theme and template by extending the simple theme and providing you own free marker template.